# How to convert Class types?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoder, sktransition

I'm trying to figure out how to convert class type so that I can go from my SKScene which is 'self' to my SCNScene which is GamePlay. And basically perform a scene normal scene transition.

[image]
Code:

```
let scene = GamePlay(coder:NSCoder())
let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast you're `scene` to `SKScene`.

```
 let scene = GamePlay(coder:NSCoder())
 let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
 if let skScene = scene as? SKScene {
        view?.presentScene(skScene, transition: transition)
 }
```